# Looping does not work to create a text file with City and pace name using C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, dictionary, foreach, text-files

I am trying to create text file which should contain a city name and interesting places name of that city. For this, initially I create a text file with City name. My City_list.txt file looks like this-

```
Flensburg
Kiel
Lübeck
Neumünster
Heide
Geesthacht
Husum
Elmshorn
Pinneberg
Wedel
...... many more
```

Now My next work is,by using the city name get all external links exist in Wikipedia article. So , I create a list to get all the city name so that it can create place name one after other. But my code is not working.I create the place list for Wedel, for the last one only. But not for flensburg to wedel. I know there is one looping problem, But could not get the point where should I modify my work. 
My code is as follows-

```
 public void PoiListFromWiki()
    {

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        string fileName = "POI.txt";
        var path = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

        List<string> ReadFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"I:\TouristPlace\TouristPlace\bin\Debug\CityList\POI_list.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")).ToList();
        foreach (string line in ReadFile)
        {


            Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(line) + "&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var responseContent = response.Content;

                    string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList(); //NulReferanceException error occurd

                    List<string> places = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in obj)
                    {
                        places.Add(item);
                    }
                    cities[line] = string.Join(";", places);

                    var output = line + ";" + cities[line];

                    File.WriteAllText(path, output); //here is problem
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

My Expected Result is

```
Flensburg;place1;place2..
Kiel;Place1;Place2..
Lübeck;Place1;Place2..
```

But With my code I got only

```
Lübeck;Place1;Place2..
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the file, your doing this inside the outer loop. Append to a stringbuilder, write at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.WrtieAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overwrites the file. You need to use [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
 public void PoiListFromWiki()
    {

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        string fileName = "POI.txt";
        var path = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

        List<string> ReadFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"I:\TouristPlace\TouristPlace\bin\Debug\CityList\POI_list.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")).ToList();
        foreach (string line in ReadFile)
        {


            Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(line) + "&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var responseContent = response.Content;

                    string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList(); //NulReferanceException error occurd

                    List<string> places = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in obj)
                    {
                        places.Add(item);
                    }
                    cities[line] = string.Join(";", places);

                    var output = line + ";" + cities[line] + "\r\n";

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                       File.WriteAllText(path, output); //here is problem
                    }
            else
            {
                File.AppendAllText(path, output);
            }
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you  It is working. I just Add "\r\n" after the line var output = line + ";" + cities[line] + "\r\n"  so that all city comes in new line. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @harry.luson . I edited my code to include your change.

Answer (score 2):

You write the output file again and again in each loop but WriteAllText overwrite everytime the previous data with the new one. But you could do a lot better than appending to the previous text. Just use a StringBuilder to store the text while you get it and write just one time after the exit from the loop.

Here the significant changes to make to your current code....

```
public void PoiListFromWiki()
{
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    .....
    foreach (string line in ReadFile)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
                ....
                cities[line] = string.Join(";", places);
                results.AppendLine(line + ";" + cities[line]);
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllText(path, results.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
public void PoiListFromWiki()
{

    var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
    string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
    string fileName = "POI.txt";
    var path = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
    var output="";
    List<string> ReadFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"I:\TouristPlace\TouristPlace\bin\Debug\CityList\POI_list.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")).ToList();
    foreach (string line in ReadFile)
    {


        Dictionary<string, string> cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(line) + "&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var responseContent = response.Content;

                string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList(); //NulReferanceException error occurd

                List<string> places = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in obj)
                {
                    places.Add(item);
                }
                cities[line] = string.Join(";", places);

                output += line + ";" + cities[line]+"/r/n"; //always add new info in string, then write it all in file

                File.WriteAllText(path, output);
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes your code is working. But could you please modify your code \r\n in this line. Because it should be like this \ instead of /. Thank you. I will accept your answer.